# For independent geometric random variables $X, Y$, what is $\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

The following question occurred to me while I was solving exercise 2.7(b) of the first edition of Mitzenmacher-Upfal. Let $X, Y$ be independent geometric random variables. Which of the following claims correctly gives the value of $\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y)$, and why?

#### Claim 1:

By the definition of conditional probability, we have

$$\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y) = \Pr(\max(X, Y) = i | X = Y) \Pr(X = Y)$$

If $X = Y$, then the event "$\max(X, Y) = i$" is equivalent to the event "$X = i \cap Y = i$". Therefore,

$$= \Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)\Pr(X = Y)$$

#### Claim 2:

The event "$\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y$" is equivalent to the event "$X = i \cap Y = i$", thus

$$\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y) = \Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first claim is wrong. $P(\max(X,Y) = i \mid X=Y)$ is actually $$\frac{P(\max(X,Y) = i \cap X=Y)}{P(X=Y)} = \frac{P(X=i \cap Y=i)}{P(X=Y)}.$$
Your mistake was dropping the conditioning on the event $X=Y$.

After this correction, both approaches give the same answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. So equivalently we could write $\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y) = \Pr(\max(X, Y) = i | X = Y)\Pr(X = Y) $ $= \Pr(X = i \cap Y = i | X = Y)\Pr(X = Y) = \frac{\Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)}{\Pr(X = Y)} \Pr(X = Y) = \Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)$, yes? But then why can't I do the following? $\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i | X = Y) = \Pr(X = i | X = Y)$

Comment: To clarify what I mean in my previous comment, what's wrong with saying $\Pr(X = i | X = Y) = \frac{\Pr(X = i \cap X = Y)}{\Pr(X = Y)}$ $=  \frac{\Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)}{\Pr(X = Y)} = \Pr(X = i \cap Y = i | X = Y) = \Pr(\max(X, Y) = i | X = Y)$?

Comment: @kotu Nothing is wrong with the work in these two comments. But what advantage do you gain by writing $P(X=i \mid X=Y)$?

Comment: I assume there is something wrong the work in my last two comments because this would allow $\Pr(\max(X, Y) = i \cap X = Y)$ $ = \Pr(\max(X, Y) = i | X = Y) \Pr(X = Y)$ $ = \Pr(X = i | X = Y) \Pr(X = Y)$ by my last two comments, which is $= \frac{\Pr(X = i)}{\Pr(X = Y)} \Pr(X = Y) = \Pr(X = i)$. This is different from the answer $\Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)$ claim 2 gives in my question that you said is correct.

Comment: Oops wait nevermind, I miscalculated.

Comment: It should be $\Pr(X = i | X = Y)\Pr(X = Y) = \frac{\Pr(X = i \cap X = Y)}{\Pr(X = Y)} \Pr(X = Y) = \Pr(X = i \cap X = Y) = \Pr(X = i \cap Y = i)$. Everything checks out now, thanks for your patience.

Comment: @kotu Nice work catching your own error! :)